# Testing fork() in Redux Saga with Jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-saga

Currently I've been trying to create some unit tests for my redux saga "getExchanges", however after going through some documentation & sites I've found that there isn't great information on running unit tests in this area.

Below is my saga that I'm trying to test & any code surrounding it.  The goal is to test to see if the saga is acting properly & ensuring that the API is pulling information in the way that it should.

Get Exchanges Saga

```
export function* getExchanges(action) {
  const state: storeType = yield select()
  yield fork(async, action, API.getExchanges, { userId: state.auth.userId })
}
```

The 'async' reference in the yield fork above

```
import { put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

import { asyncAction } from './asyncAction'

export const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

/**
 * @description: Reusable asynchronous action flow
 *
 * @param action  : redux action
 * @param apiFn   : api to call
 * @param payload : payload to send via api
 */
export function* async(action, apiFn, payload) {
  const async = asyncAction(action.type)
  try {
    const { response, data } = yield call(apiFn, payload)
    console.log(`[Saga-API_SUCCEED - ${action.type}, ${response}, ]: , ${data}`)
    yield put(async.success(data))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`[Saga-API_FAILED: - , ${action.type}, ]: , ${err}`)
    yield put(async.failure(err))
  }
}
```

getExchanges Action

```
export const getExchanges = () => action(actionTypes.GET_EXCHANGES.REQUEST, {})
```

GET_EXCHANGES Action type

```
export const GET_EXCHANGES = createAsyncActionTypes('GET_EXCHANGES')
```

asyncAction (wraps the getExchanges action with action() & wraps GET_EXCHANGES with createAsyncActionTypes)

```
export type ASYNC_ACTION_TYPE = {
  REQUEST: string
  SUCCESS: string
  FAILURE: string,
}

export const createAsyncActionTypes = (baseType: string): ASYNC_ACTION_TYPE => {
  return {
    REQUEST: `${baseType}`,
    SUCCESS: `${baseType}_SUCCESS`,
    FAILURE: `${baseType}_FAILURE`,
  }
}

export function action(type, payload = {}) {
  return { type, payload }
}

export function asyncAction(actionType: string) {
  const asyncActionType = createAsyncActionTypes(actionType)
  return {
    success: response => action(asyncActionType.SUCCESS, response),
    failure: err => action(asyncActionType.FAILURE, err),
  }
}
```

getExchanges API

```
 export const getExchanges = ({ userId }) => API.request(`/exchange/${userId}`, 'GET')
```

My stab at a jest test case

```
    import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
    import { runSaga } from 'redux'
    import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
    import { exchangesSaga, getExchanges ,getBalances, selectExchange } from '../src/sagas/exchanges.saga'
    import * as api from '../src/api/transaction'
    import * as actionTypes from '../src/action-types/exchanges.action-types'
    import { action } from '../src/sagas/asyncAction'

    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
    const mockStore = configureMockStore([sagaMiddleware]);

    export async function recordSaga(saga, initialAction) {
        const dispatched = [];

        // Run's a given saga outside of the middleware
        await runSaga(
        {
            // dispatch fulfills put
            dispatch: (action) => dispatched.push(action)
        },
        saga,
        initialAction
        ).done;

        return dispatched;
    }

    describe.only("getExchanges saga", () => {
        api.getExchanges = jest.fn()
        beforeEach(() => {
            jest.resetAllMocks()
        })

        it('should get exchanges from API and call success action', async () => {
            const getUserExchanges = {exchange, exchange2};
            api.getExchanges.mockImplementation(() => getExchanges);

            const initialAction = action(actionTypes.GET_EXCHANGES.REQUEST)
            const dispatched = await recordSaga(
            getExchanges,
            initialAction
            );

            expect(api.getExchanges).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
            expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(action(actionTypes.GET_EXCHANGES.SUCCESS));
        });
    })
```

I'm currently not getting much out of my test case as it's incomplete & I'm kinda lost on how I should go about doing this.

I'm expecting to be able to return the test & ensure that the API is pulling the information correctly using the mock data

Comment: What does `return the test` mean?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [redux-saga-test-plan](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan).

It lets you [expect](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/effect-creators.html) that certain effects are being yielded, and it lets you [mock](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/mocking/static-providers.html) any effect.